# Java Applet Security Issues

Tags: java, html, security, applet

I'm having a lot of difficulty getting an applet I made to run in a web browser. Java security keeps blocking it. I have the jar sitting on my desktop and I made a simple html file that embeds the jar using . I'm trying to embed this in html for my website. I don't have any root access to the site at all so I want to avoid using Web Start and Apache Tom Cat stuff because it seems those tutorials assume you're uploading the app itself to the directory of the site itself. I can only embed html here, so I have a jar located in my googledrive.com/host that I'm trying to link.

Here's the code for the tag.

```html
<applet  
    codebase="https://bb2f18b1cb19b925c50b747c1c65afcc4ad11720.googledrive.com/host/0B34NA0csYJZufm5ZeFFEcUMyQnR5bmw1eVl2M3BOcXItNGxxZTZvaFExNVhXQnY4dzY3QTg"  
    archive="AsteroidGameApp.jar"  
    code="asteroidgame.AsteroidGame.class" 
    width=500 
    height=500>
</applet>
```

I don't even know if it would run correctly or not because I can't get past the security. I've read stuff about getting the code signed but I can't find a clear tutorial how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As reported on the [Java related site](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml) Starting with Java 7 Update 51, trying to run unsigned Java applications generates error messages and prevents executing the applet.

Follow the instructions about the [Oracle proper solution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/rsa_signing.html) (I my experience I had to get a valid certificate from a trusted root like [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/static/030998.pdf) and then used this certificate to sign my applet jar) but if you can't do this way, try the suggested workaround in the correspondent section.

Obviously, as stated by the Java site:

> It is highly recommended not to run these types of applications. However if you still want to run these apps, run only if you understand the risks and implications.

Comment: What instructions? That's what I'm here asking for. A lot of the workarounds I keep bumping into on Google show how to in the local security settings, but I don't want to have to tell my site visitors to do all that just to show off a class project.
How does Verisign work?

Comment: Update with some info about jar signig and how Verisign works